# 403 Forbidden Error Objective c to PHP

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, http

I have a very diverse script that makes a GET http call in objective c, but in return I receive a 403 Forbidden error server-side...

My objective c code...

```
NSString *result = (__bridge NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)videoURL, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);


NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webprogramming360.com/VideoPush/plist/urlTrans.php?videoID=%@",result];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connect) {
    NSLog(@"Successful!  =----= %d",[result length]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}
```

It's very simple and it actually works if you change the urlString object to this...

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webprogramming360.com/VideoPush/plist/urlTrans.php?videoID=1"];
```

But the code doesn't work the other way... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webprogramming360.com/VideoPush/plist/urlTrans.php?videoID=%i", [result intValue]];
```

Comment: That gets through with no errors, but it basically sends a random number... What else???